# Xcode 14.2 Organizer -> Crashes shows multiple devices for each crash but no data from crash log

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to find the reason for multiple app crashes. App Store Connect shows multiple crashes but the Organizer in Xcode lists a lot of crashes but very few entries have any data.
Image is only one of many cases in the organizer.  2nd column from left shows 3 devices but right column shows 0 devices.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Crashes column was set to Last Year but statistics was set to Last Two Weeks, thus many in last year were not relevant.